# lowering/raising indices

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Given that $x_i \equiv g_{ij}x^j$.
How do you change $\langle x, y \rangle _V = x^i g_{ij}y^j$ to $\langle x, y \rangle _V = x_i y^i$ using the index lowering method?.

The index of summation doesn't matter so you can swap the roles of j and i but given that the positions of x and y in the summation is important, how can you switch it up like that.

And Generally, why is $\langle x, y \rangle _V = x^i g_{ij}y^j$ and not something like $\langle x, y \rangle _V = x^i y^j g_{ij}$ or $\langle x, y \rangle _V = y^j g_{ij}x^i$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The order is not important. Each $x^i$ is a real number (the $i$'th coordinate of $\vec x$), and summing such expressions over $i$ or $j$ gives real numbers, which commute.

Comment: So the orders only matter if the summaton equation were to be written as a matrix equation say: $X^{T}GY$(Because $X^{T}YG$ wouldn't make any sense). I think I get it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing going on here. As you already understand, the ordering of the terms is irrelevant because multiplication of real numbers is commutative and associative. Perhaps it helps to put in the summation symbols explicitly:

$$g_{ij}x^iy^j = \sum_{i,j} g_{ij}x^iy^j = \sum_j\left(\sum_i g_{ij}x^i\right) y^j = \sum_j x_jy^j = x_jy^j = x_iy^i.$$

Comment: Yes, it is very clear now. Thank you very much!